# Y axis camera movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have been making movement for a 3D FPS, everything works well except for the camera movement.

I have it set to rotate the rigid body on the X axis based on the cursor, and to rotate the camera on the Y axis based one the cursor.

The problem is that the Y axis has no limits, you can look behind you or even do multiple 360 turns. I have no experience with Clamp.

My two scripts controlling the player.

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(PlayerMotor))]
public class PlayerControler : MonoBehaviour {

    private float speed = 5f;

    float lookSensitivity = 70f;

    private PlayerMotor motor;

    void Start ()
    {
        motor = GetComponent<PlayerMotor>();
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        float _xMov = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float _zMov = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 _movHorizontal = transform.right * _xMov;
        Vector3 _movVertical = transform.forward * _zMov;

        Vector3 _velocity = (_movHorizontal + _movVertical).normalized * speed;

        motor.Move(_velocity);

        //Turning

        float _yRot = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");

        Vector3 _rotation = new Vector3 (0f, _yRot, 0f) * lookSensitivity;

        motor.Rotate(_rotation);

        //Camera Rotation

        float _xRot = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        Vector3 _cameraRotation = new Vector3 (_xRot, 0f, 0f) * lookSensitivity;

        motor.RotateCamera(-_cameraRotation);
    }
}
```

---

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]

public class PlayerMotor : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    private Camera cam;

    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
    private Vector3 rotation = Vector3.zero;
    private Vector3 cameraRotation = Vector3.zero;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    void Start ()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    public void Move (Vector3 _velocity)
    {
        velocity = _velocity;
    }

    public void Rotate (Vector3 _rotation)
    {
        rotation = _rotation;
    }

    public void RotateCamera (Vector3 _cameraRotation)
    {
        cameraRotation = _cameraRotation;
    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        PerformMovement();
        PreformRotation();

    }

    void PerformMovement ()
    {
        if (velocity != Vector3.zero)
        {
            rb.MovePosition(rb.position + velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
    }

    void PreformRotation ()
    {
        rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * Quaternion.Euler (rotation));

        if (cam != null)
        { 
            cam.transform.Rotate(cameraRotation);
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = false;

        }
            /*cameraRotation = Mathf.Clamp(cameraRotation.x, -89f, 89f);
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = false;
        localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(cameraRotation, rotation, 0);*/
    }
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to restrict the x rotation between a maximum and minimum value, which is what clamping means.

After this line

`float _xRot = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");`

FIrst make sure the angle is between 0 and 360:

```
if (_xRot < -360F) _xRot += 360F;
if (_xRot > 360F) _xRot -= 360F;
```

Then restrict it between a max and min:

```
float min = -70f;
float max = 70f;
_xRot = Mathf.Clamp(_xRot, min, max);
```